Create a subset dataframe when values in one dataframe match a condition of a defined value in another dataframe in R
I'm trying to create a subset dataframe (df3) when value of 1 in col1 (df1) matches value of 1 in signal (df2) at the same timestamp (datetime). The new dataframe should include datetime, col1 and signal.  I've seen many other questions on stackoverflow but none of them match what I'm trying to do.
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

# Generate datetime sequence in 15-minute intervals for both dataframes
start_time_df1 <- ymd_hms("2024-01-01 00:00:00")
datetime_df1 <- seq(from = start_time_df1, by = "15 mins", length.out = 20)

start_time_df2 <- ymd_hms("2024-01-01 00:00:00")
datetime_df2 <- seq(from = start_time_df2, by = "15 mins", length.out = 35)

# Generate random signal values (either 1 or 0) for both dataframes
set.seed(123)  # for reproducibility
signal_df1 <- sample(c(0, 1), size = 20, replace = TRUE)

col1_df1<- sample(c(0, 1), size = 20, replace = TRUE)

set.seed(456)  # different seed for df2 to ensure different random values
signal_df2 <- sample(c(0, 1), size = 35, replace = TRUE)

# Create the dataframes
df1 <- data.frame(datetime = datetime_df1, Col1= col1_df1)
df2 <- data.frame(datetime = datetime_df2, signal = signal_df2)

str(df1)
#> 'data.frame':    20 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ datetime: POSIXct, format: "2024-01-01 00:00:00" "2024-01-01 00:15:00" ...
#>  $ Col1    : num  0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 ...
str(df2)
#> 'data.frame':    35 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ datetime: POSIXct, format: "2024-01-01 00:00:00" "2024-01-01 00:15:00" ...
#>  $ signal  : num  0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...

# Print the dataframes
print(df1)
#>               datetime Col1
#> 1  2024-01-01 00:00:00    0
#> 2  2024-01-01 00:15:00    1
#> 3  2024-01-01 00:30:00    0
#> 4  2024-01-01 00:45:00    0
#> 5  2024-01-01 01:00:00    0
#> 6  2024-01-01 01:15:00    0
#> 7  2024-01-01 01:30:00    1
#> 8  2024-01-01 01:45:00    1
#> 9  2024-01-01 02:00:00    0
#> 10 2024-01-01 02:15:00    1
#> 11 2024-01-01 02:30:00    0
#> 12 2024-01-01 02:45:00    1
#> 13 2024-01-01 03:00:00    0
#> 14 2024-01-01 03:15:00    1
#> 15 2024-01-01 03:30:00    1
#> 16 2024-01-01 03:45:00    0
#> 17 2024-01-01 04:00:00    0
#> 18 2024-01-01 04:15:00    0
#> 19 2024-01-01 04:30:00    0
#> 20 2024-01-01 04:45:00    1
print(df2)
#>               datetime signal
#> 1  2024-01-01 00:00:00      0
#> 2  2024-01-01 00:15:00      0
#> 3  2024-01-01 00:30:00      0
#> 4  2024-01-01 00:45:00      1
#> 5  2024-01-01 01:00:00      0
#> 6  2024-01-01 01:15:00      1
#> 7  2024-01-01 01:30:00      0
#> 8  2024-01-01 01:45:00      0
#> 9  2024-01-01 02:00:00      1
#> 10 2024-01-01 02:15:00      0
#> 11 2024-01-01 02:30:00      1
#> 12 2024-01-01 02:45:00      0
#> 13 2024-01-01 03:00:00      0
#> 14 2024-01-01 03:15:00      1
#> 15 2024-01-01 03:30:00      0
#> 16 2024-01-01 03:45:00      0
#> 17 2024-01-01 04:00:00      0
#> 18 2024-01-01 04:15:00      1
#> 19 2024-01-01 04:30:00      1
#> 20 2024-01-01 04:45:00      1
#> 21 2024-01-01 05:00:00      0
#> 22 2024-01-01 05:15:00      0
#> 23 2024-01-01 05:30:00      1
#> 24 2024-01-01 05:45:00      1
#> 25 2024-01-01 06:00:00      0
#> 26 2024-01-01 06:15:00      0
#> 27 2024-01-01 06:30:00      0
#> 28 2024-01-01 06:45:00      1
#> 29 2024-01-01 07:00:00      1
#> 30 2024-01-01 07:15:00      0
#> 31 2024-01-01 07:30:00      0
#> 32 2024-01-01 07:45:00      1
#> 33 2024-01-01 08:00:00      1
#> 34 2024-01-01 08:15:00      1
#> 35 2024-01-01 08:30:00      0

Any help greatly appreciated.

Something like library(dplyr); left_join(df1, df2) %>% filter(Col1 == 1 & signal == 1) ?

That worked! If you add it as an answer (instead of a comment) I'll mark it as the solution

I'd gladly do that, but I fear it's very likely a duplicate. Let's see if the system can work it out... :)

Using a joining operation with a filter will get you matching rows with the desired condition
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2) %>% 
  filter(Col1 == 1 & signal == 1)
Joining with `by = join_by(datetime)`
             datetime Col1 signal
1 2024-01-01 03:15:00    1      1
2 2024-01-01 04:45:00    1      1


For larger data, maybe more efficient to use inner_join(df1 |> filter(Col1 == 1), df2 |> filter(signal == 1)) to avoid making the larger intermediate table.

@JonSpring True, would be interesting to see the speedup for large datasets though since I think the joining operation is quite efficient even for vast ones (ultimately comparing the speed of filter with that of join).

Yes, for many cases the difference negligible. For df1 N= 1E5 and df2 N= 35E3, the time difference was 16x (9 sec vs. 0.5 sec). For much larger N the left_join would exhaust memory.
